# Assertion in callback not working

Tags: javascript

I have an assertion in the following code. I'm testing out a failure. I don't see an assertion error and instead see the following warning at the end.

```
var sendData = {msg:"Hello1"};

console.log("Send Data: "+util.inspect(sendData));
sendQueue.add(sendData);

receiveQueue.process(function (job, done) {
    var receivedData = job.data;
    console.log("Received data: ", util.inspect(receivedData));

    //FORCE FAILURE
    assert(1,2));

    done();
});
```

Output:

```
Send Data: { msg: 'Hello1' }
Received data:  { msg: 'Hello1' } 
(node:16972) Warning: a promise was created in a handler at /usr/apps/myapp/node_modules/bull/lib/queue.js:688:9 but was not returned from it, see ...
at new Promise (/usr/apps/myapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
(node:16972) Warning: .then() only accepts functions but was passed: [object Object]
```

Comment: `assert` will throw an error if the assertion fails. What does `receiveQueue.process` do if an error is thrown? It seems that somewhere you or a library (more likely you) are not passing a valid value to `.then`. `assert` causes some promise to be rejected, but the rejected promise isn't taken care of.

Comment: you added an object to sendQueue which expects a function maybe? `sendQueue.add(()=>({msg:'hello'}))` ?